# Should I set RUBYLIB to 'lib' on my development box?

Tags: ruby

There doesn't seem to be an accepted best practice for handling the Ruby load path during development. Is there a compelling reason NOT to just set RUBYLIB in my dotfiles and fuggedaboutit?

Comment: Not at all. That's pretty much why RUBYLIB exists in the first place.

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do, most of us would use [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) or [RVM](http://rvm.io/rvm/install) to handle multiple Ruby installations. They'll manage changing your Ruby load paths and gem directory for you.